# How many virtual table is created for the following code?

Tags: c++, vtable

I am  learning c++ and got one question about the virtual table ,help me in understanding this.
I want to know how many tables are created in this program.

```
 #include <iostream>
    class A { public: virtual void f() { } };
    class B : public A { };
    class C : public B { };
```

Comment: Assuming *any* vtables are created (that is an *implementation detail* of the compiler, not dictated by the standard), then there would likely be 3 vtables, one for each class, but those 3 vtables would be pointing at the same copy of `f()` since there is no overridden copy involved in this code.

Comment: Compiler can do whatever the heck it wants. Could be zero v-tables if the compiler's got a better way to do it.

Comment: It's implementation defined.  No one is most like in your example, since you don't override the virtual method.

Answer (score 3):

> How many virtual table is created for the following code?

The C++ language does not define such thing as a virtual table. It is a way to implement virtual dispatch. Since it is an implementation detail, the number of virtual tables is not defined by the language either and it is up to the language implementation to decide.

As such, there is no answer unless the question is restricted to some particular language implementation. Using an example language implementation, a virtual table was created for each of these classes:

```
std::exception
std::bad_exception
std::type_info
std::bad_cast
std::bad_typeid
std::bad_alloc
std::bad_array_new_length
std::nested_exception
__cxxabiv1::__forced_unwind
std::locale::facet
std::__cxx11::collate<char>
std::__cxx11::collate<wchar_t>
std::__cxx11::collate_byname<char>
std::__cxx11::collate_byname<wchar_t>
std::logic_error
std::domain_error
std::invalid_argument
std::length_error
std::out_of_range
std::runtime_error
std::range_error
std::overflow_error
std::underflow_error
std::_V2::error_category
std::system_error
std::ios_base::failure
std::ios_base
std::basic_streambuf<char>
std::basic_streambuf<wchar_t>
std::ctype<char>
std::__ctype_abstract_base<wchar_t>
std::ctype<wchar_t>
std::ctype_byname<char>
std::ctype_byname<wchar_t>
std::__cxx11::numpunct<char>
std::__cxx11::numpunct<wchar_t>
std::__cxx11::numpunct_byname<char>
std::num_get<char>
std::num_put<char>
std::__cxx11::numpunct_byname<wchar_t>
std::num_get<wchar_t>
std::num_put<wchar_t>
std::basic_ios<char>
std::basic_ios<wchar_t>
std::basic_ostream<char>
std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>
std::basic_istream<char>
std::basic_istream<wchar_t>
std::basic_iostream<char>
std::basic_iostream<wchar_t>
A
B
C
```

Here is the command I used to generate the list:

```
g++ -fdump-lang-class -std=c++17 main.cpp \
    && grep Vtable main.cpp.*.class \
     | cut -f 3 -d ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is 3 virtual tables. You have created 3 classes here, so that means this code will be having 3 virtual tables.

Comment: Why can't there be just one virtual table?

Comment: @user975989 because there are 3 different classes. User code could create any one of them at any time. And the compiler needs to be able to dereference a pointer to any one of them to access a valid vtable. So there needs to be 3 separate vtables.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - And any of those objects can be made to point at just *one* vtable. The same exact functions will be called. "But what about RTTI", you'll likely say. Well, it isn't used in the code sample. A compiler *could* prove that single vtable may not need RTTI info, and so can be reused (it might also be helped by compiler flags). That's why those questions (and attempts to answer them) are moot when asked in the most general way.